# Bootstrap: button styles not showing properly in React/Rails/Webpacker setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I have a `Rails 6` project set up with `Webpacker` & `React`. I installed `Bootstap` via yarn and is configure to work with webpacker. Everything is seems to work except `buttons` background color comes in a shade of black.  I have spent hours trying to figure out why with no luck. For example the following button will not render in primary color blue as it should.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button> **do not render properly**
```

**/packs/stylesheets/application.scss:**

```
`@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";`
```

**/packs/application.js:**

```
import 'bootstrap'
import './stylesheets/application'
```

**config/webpack/environment.js looks like this:**

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker');

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.append('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
 })
);

environment.loaders.append("graphql", {
  test: /\.(graphql|gql)$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: 'graphql-tag/loader',
});

module.exports = environment;
```

Any help you could provide is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

> Why are you using `class` attribute in the button-tag?

That should be `className`, right?

---

Moreover, I'm using these configurations(seems similar to yours) and working flawlessly,

- **Versions**

  - "@rails/webpacker": "4.2.2"
  - "bootstrap": "^4.4.1"
  - Rails 6.0.1
- **Project-structure for packs**,

  [image: project-strucutre]
- **Imports**

  - application.sccs

    ```
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
    ```
  - hello_react.jsx

    ```
    import './scss/application.scss';
    ```
- **`hello_react.jsx` holds the `root` component**

  ```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      ReactDOM.render(
          <Provider store={store}>
              <App/>
          </Provider>,
          document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')),
      )
  })
  ```
- **config/webpack/environment.js**

  ```
  const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

  module.exports = environment
  ```
- **Demo**

  ```
  <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
  ```

  [image]

Comment: Shekhar, yes I'm using className in my code. You are right our configs seems similar, except `config/webpack/environment.js`. I have added `jquery` and `popper.js` based on Gorails tutorial [link] (https://gorails.com/episodes/how-to-use-bootstrap-with-webpack-and-rails). Our versions are different.: `@rails/webpacker": "^4.0.7"`, `bootstrap": "4.3.1"`, `Rails 6.0.0` but not sure if this will cause an issue??

Comment: I don't think versions are causing the issues - maybe your downloaded modules have been broken. 1) try to reinstall them 2) I don't prefer to use `jquery` in react app [see this blog](https://medium.com/@wisecobbler/if-you-think-you-need-jquery-in-your-react-app-you-re-doing-it-wrong-77899ed7217e) - it may help you :)

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll try reinstalling bootstrap and see what happens.

Comment: I reinstalled bootstrap, but didn't work. It's seems like `<button>` tag is locked. I'm unable to even edit it through chrome dev tools. Very strange!! Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: @BhatiyaJ I'm not able to reproduce the issue, can you update(if possible) your ([reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) question?

Comment: OK seems like I fixed it after removing `#= require_tree .` from `application.scss` file. May be something to do with `Activeadmin` overwriting css.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved!! It seems like the issue was related to `Activeadmin`, but not sure. But, after removing `#= require_tree .` from `assets/stylesheets/application.scss`, it worked.